# BrowserSync is not working on the root dir

Tags: javascript, gulp, browser-sync, gulp-browser-sync

[BrowserSync](https://www.npmjs.com/package/browser-sync) gulp plugin, Is not reloading the browser page while the view is on the `index.html` which means `localhost:3000`

```
gulp.task("browserSync", function () {
  browserSync.init({
    server: {
      baseDir: "./public"
    }
  });
});

gulp.task("liveReload", [
  "browserSync", "copy", "watch"
], function () {
  gulp.watch("src/**/*.html", browserSync.reload);
});
```

it's reloading only when the URL is pointing to other .html pages. like: `localhost:3000/en/pricing.html`

Project Structure:

**src**

```
index.html
/html
  pricing.html
  ...
```

**Public**

```
index.html
 /en
  pricing.html
  ...
 /ar
  pricing.html
  ...
```

What is my code issue?